# Flipping images from left to right and from top to bottom

Tags: c, arrays, flip

I made two functions where one flips the image from left to right and the other one flips the image from top to bottom.  But for some reason, when I load the image, nothing happened to the images.

This is the code for flipping from left to right.

```
void flip_horizontal( uint8_t array[], 
              unsigned int cols, 
              unsigned int rows )
{
    unsigned int left = 0;
    unsigned int right = cols;
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
    while(left != right && right > left)
        {
        int temp = array[r * cols+ left];
        array[(r * cols) + left] = array[(r * cols) + cols - right];
        array[(r * cols) + cols - right] = temp;
        right++;
        left++;
        } 
    }
}
```

And this is the code for flipping from top to bottom.

```
void flip_vertical( uint8_t array[], 
            unsigned int cols, 
            unsigned int rows )
{
    unsigned int top = 0;
    unsigned int bottom = rows;
    for(int r = 0; r < cols; r++)
    {
    while(top != bottom && bottom > top)
        {
        int temp = array[r * rows+ top];
        array[(r * rows) + top] = array[(r * rows) + rows - bottom];
        array[(r * rows) + rows - bottom] = temp;
        bottom++;
        top++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is a homework question you should mark it as such in the tags.

Comment: @JonCage, [there is not such tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: Fair point. Let me correct that; If this is homework, it should be marked as such in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving these inside your `for` loop:

```
unsigned int left = 0;
unsigned int right = cols;

unsigned int top = 0;
unsigned int bottom = rows;
```

Otherwise, you will only flip the first row/column.

There are some other issues in the way you're indexing as well but I won't spoil the fun of fixing those :-)